# Cross Browser Compatibility Issues

Tags: cross-browser

[My site](http://www.thezenapproach.com)  looks fine in firefox but in internet explorer everything seems to be bigger so the sizing on the page looks wrong. I really have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: This is a **CSS/HTML/Browser** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: Nick - I think usually the mods will migrate it for you...

Answer (score 0):

Start with your code errors [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   thezenapproach.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.thezenapproach.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). (scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.) You can ignore the "unencoded ampersand" errors.

And try a transitional doc type rather than strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```